# Send raw transaction data with contract dependencies

Tags: solidity, web3js, testrpc

I have a solidity contract that creates another contract:

```
    contract Factory {
    function createContract () returns (address){
        address newContract = new test(msg.sender);
        return newContract;
    } 
}

contract test {
 address public creator;
    function test (address _creator){
    creator=_creator;
    }
}
```

This works great.
But my question is sending Raw transactions, namely , what is the payload data and/or data in the field?  How does this contract know the other ABI?

```
var solidityFunction = new SolidityFunction('',Factory_ABI, '');
var payloadData = solidityFunction.toPayload([]).data;

const txData = {
  nonce: web3.toHex(txCount),
  gasLimit: gLimit,
  gasPrice: web3.toHex(gPrice),
  from: account1,
  value: web3.toHex(web3.toWei(0, 'wei')),
  data: payloadData,
}
```

The code to deploy it works great if I just deploy the test contract, but as soon as I try to deploy 'Factory' I get a 'stack underflow' error and I think it has something to do with that data field.

Oh and I'm on the testrpc if that matters